# How to regex just last / (if exists more than once)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to remove just the string after the last slash if there is no other slash right before it.

I am trying to use this regex `/(?:.(?!/))+$` but it does not remove what I want.

I need to transform the below URLs.

From:

```
    http://69.162.64.252:8692/live
    http://rvn01.painelstream.net:8638
    http://2.stm-ip.com:8578/;stream.mp3
    http://stm51.streamingbage.net.br:18164
    http://audio1.cmaudioevideo.com:8346/stream
    http://radio.radionaturezafm.com.br:9994
    http://srv-stream.sisdera.com:8000/SOCIEDADECARNAVA
    http://stm1.srvaudio.com.br:9422/;type=mp3
    https://streaming.speedrs.com.br/radio/8050/jaboticaba
    http://hts03.kshost.com.br:8014/live
```

Expected:

```
    http://69.162.64.252:8692
    http://rvn01.painelstream.net:8638
    http://2.stm-ip.com:8578
    http://stm51.streamingbage.net.br:18164
    http://audio1.cmaudioevideo.com:8346
    http://radio.radionaturezafm.com.br:9994
    http://srv-stream.sisdera.com:8000
    http://stm1.srvaudio.com.br:9422
    https://streaming.speedrs.com.br/radio/8050
    http://hts03.kshost.com.br:8014
```

But the actual result is:

```
    http://69.162.64.252:8692
    http:
    http://2.stm-ip.com:8578
    http:
    http://audio1.cmaudioevideo.com:8346
    http:
    http://srv-stream.sisdera.com:8000
    http://stm1.srvaudio.com.br:9422
    https://streaming.speedrs.com.br/radio/8050
    http://hts03.kshost.com.br:8014
```

See my [attempt demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC6yX1/24).

Comment: Using .split("/")[-1] you will get last part, if you want firt part, "/".join(yourstring.split("/")[:-1])

Comment: You [might try](https://regex101.com/r/UL7wzJ/1) `(?<!/)/[^/]*$`, but there are other ways to work with URLs in Python, e.g. using [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew there are? I don't know how other ways

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if you want to add as an Answer, just to check as answered this question, feel free =)

Comment: Someone suggests that is a completely irrelevant answer. Probably you should use other solutions.

Comment: this solved my problem, that's what I know! haha thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a regex, you may use

```
(?<!/)/[^/]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UL7wzJ/1).

**Details**

- `(?<!/)` - no `/` right before is allowed
- `/` - a `/` char
- `[^/]*` - 0 or more chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
s = "http://69.162.64.252:8692/live"
gs = "/".join(s.split("/")[:-1])
```

OUTPUT

```
'http://69.162.64.252:8692'
```

Comment: http://69.162.64.252:8692
http:/
http://2.stm-ip.com:8578
http:/
http://audio1.cmaudioevideo.com:8346
http:/

didn't work

Answer (score 1):

A naive solution with no regex using [`.rindex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rindex). Note that it is applied only if the url has more than 2 `/`:

```
urls = ['http://69.162.64.252:8692/live',
        'http://rvn01.painelstream.net:8638',
        'http://2.stm-ip.com:8578/;stream.mp3',
        'http://stm51.streamingbage.net.br:18164',
        'http://audio1.cmaudioevideo.com:8346/stream',
        'http://radio.radionaturezafm.com.br:9994',
        'http://srv-stream.sisdera.com:8000/SOCIEDADECARNAVA',
        'http://stm1.srvaudio.com.br:9422/;type=mp3',
        'https://streaming.speedrs.com.br/radio/8050/jaboticaba',
        'http://hts03.kshost.com.br:8014/live']

for url in urls:
    if url.count('/') > 2:
        url = url[:url.rindex('/')]
    print(url)
```

outputs

```
http://69.162.64.252:8692
http://rvn01.painelstream.net:8638
http://2.stm-ip.com:8578
http://stm51.streamingbage.net.br:18164
http://audio1.cmaudioevideo.com:8346
http://radio.radionaturezafm.com.br:9994
http://srv-stream.sisdera.com:8000
http://stm1.srvaudio.com.br:9422
https://streaming.speedrs.com.br/radio/8050
http://hts03.kshost.com.br:8014
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rsplit('/', 1)` on urls with more than two `/`, this will remove the first `/` from the end of the url

```
urls = ['http://69.162.64.252:8692/live', 'http://rvn01.painelstream.net:8638', 'http://2.stm-ip.com:8578/;stream.mp3', 'http://stm51.streamingbage.net.br:18164', 'http://audio1.cmaudioevideo.com:8346/stream', 'http://radio.radionaturezafm.com.br:9994', 'http://srv-stream.sisdera.com:8000/SOCIEDADECARNAVA', 'http://stm1.srvaudio.com.br:9422/;type=mp3', 'https://streaming.speedrs.com.br/radio/8050/jaboticaba', 'http://hts03.kshost.com.br:8014/live']
results = [url.rsplit('/', 1)[0] if url.count('/') > 2 else url for url in urls]

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Output

```
http://69.162.64.252:8692
http://rvn01.painelstream.net:8638
http://2.stm-ip.com:8578
http://stm51.streamingbage.net.br:18164
http://audio1.cmaudioevideo.com:8346
http://radio.radionaturezafm.com.br:9994
http://srv-stream.sisdera.com:8000
http://stm1.srvaudio.com.br:9422
https://streaming.speedrs.com.br/radio/8050
http://hts03.kshost.com.br:8014
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try (?

@Wiktor Stribiżew

This regex, solved my problem.
Thanks!